# Collection from a sequence that constitute a perfect square

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, subsequence

Given the sequence [OEIS A033581](http://oeis.org/A033581), which is the infinite sequence, the **n**'th term (0-indexing) is given by the closed form formula **6 × n<sup>2</sup>** .

Your task is to write code, which outputs all the subsets of the set of N first numbers in the sequence, such that the sum of the subset is a perfect square.

## Rules

- The integer `N` is given as input.
- You cannot reuse a number already used in the sum. (that is, each number can appear in each subset at most once)
- Numbers used can be non-consecutive.
- Code with the least size wins.

## Example

The given sequence is {0,6,24,54,96,...,15000}

One of the required subsets will be {6,24,294}, because

```
6+24+294 = 324 = 18^2
```

You need to find all such sets of all possible lengths in the given range.

Comment: Good first post! You may consider adding examples and test cases. For future reference, we have a [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) that you can trial your ideas in.

Comment: Is this asking us to calculate A033581 given N? Or am I not understanding this correctly?

Comment: @ATaco Like for a sequence (1,9,35,39...) 1+9+39=49 a perfect square (It uses 3 numbers), 35+1= 36 another perfect square but it uses 2 numbers. So {1,35} is the required set.

Comment: @prog_SAHIL Adding that, and a few more, as examples to the post would be helpful :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71382/discussion-between-prog-sahil-and-jonathan-allan).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Ý¨n6*æʒOÅ²
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/8wNWFiMWX//8OdwqhuNirDpsqST8OFwrL//zEw)**

### How?

```
Ý¨n6*æʒOÅ² || Full program. I'll call the input N.

Ý          || 0-based inclusive range. Push [0, N] ∩ ℤ.
 ¨         || Remove the last element.
  n        || Square (element-wise).
   6*      || Multiply by 6.
     æ     || Powerset.
      ʒ    || Filter-keep those which satisfy the following:
       O   ||---| Their sum...
        Å² ||---| ... Is a perfect square?
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>114 104 103</s> 86 bytes

```hs
f n=[x|x<-concat<$>mapM(\x->[[],[x*x*6]])[0..n-1],sum x==[y^2|y<-[0..],y^2>=sum x]!!0]
```

Thanks to [Laikoni](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56433/laikoni) and [Ørjan Johansen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66041/%C3%98rjan-johansen) for most of the golfing! :)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcmxDoIwFEDR3a94EAYlLSkOTG2/QCfH8kwalEikDwIlKQn/XsXN8dz7svP72fcxtkDKhC1I3gzUWC8z7ex4PdaBa2OQmZCHvEI8GVEUxEtk8@IgKGXW@3lbJd87si@0@h1MEoHR2Y5AwWM4AIxTRx4yaKHatfibny4EaU3p3y1F/AA)

The slightly more readable version:

```hs
--  OEIS A033581
ns=map((*6).(^2))[0..]

-- returns all subsets of a list (including the empty subset)
subsets :: [a] -> [[a]]
subsets[]=[[]]
subsets(x:y)=subsets y++map(x:)(subsets y)

-- returns True if the element is present in a sorted list
t#(x:xs)|t>x=t#xs|1<2=t==x

-- the function that returns the square subsets
f :: Int -> [[Int]]
f n = filter (\l->sum l#(map(^2)[0..])) $ subsets (take n ns)
```

Comment: @Laikoni That is very ingenious! Thanks!

Comment: @Laikoni Right! Thanks!

Comment: 86 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcmxDoIwFEDR3a94EAYlLSkOTG2/QCfH8kwalEikDwIlKQn/XsXN8dz7svP72fcxtkDKhC1I3gzUWC8z7ex4PdaBa2OQmZCHvEI8GVEUxEtk8@IgKGXW@3lbJd87si@0@h1MEoHR2Y5AwWM4AIxTRx4yaKHatfibny4EaU3p3y1F/AA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 12 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to Mr. Xcoder

```
fsI@sT2ym*6*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P63Y06E4xKgyV8tM6/9/QwMA)

2 more bytes need to be added to remove `[]` and `[0]`, but they seem like valid output to me!

---

Explanataion

```
    fsI@sT2ym*6*
    f                  filter
           y           the listified powerset of
            m*6*ddQ    the listified sequence {0,6,24,...,$input-th result}
        sT             where the sum of the sub-list
     sI@  2            is invariant over int parsing after square rooting
```

Comment: 12 bytes: `fsI@sT2ym*6*`.

Comment: That's the square checking golf I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), <s>145</s> ... 97 bytes

```
import StdEnv
@n=[[]:[[6*i^2:b]\\i<-[0..n-1],b<- @i]]
f=filter((\e=or[i^2==e\\i<-[0..e]])o sum)o@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pc27CsIwFADQvV@RsRVT1KFDaSCDDoJbx@QKaZuUC3lIkgr@vLGT@4EzW618cWHZrCZOoS/oXiFmMubl5t8V90wI6IXoDvi89BNIiQMVp7b19AzHaaCEI0BlmEGbdaxrqVmIYseM6T/WAE0gaXNN4GXMag8YMaQr39lYtaZC749y/XjlcE4/)

Uses the helper function `@` to generate the power set to `n` terms by concatenating each term of `[[],[6*n^2],...]` with each term of `[[],[6*(n-1)*2],...]` recursively, and in reverse order.

The partial function `f` is then composed (where `->` denotes `o` composition) as:
`apply @ -> take the elements where -> the sum -> is a square`

Unfortunately it isn't possible to skip the `f=` and provide a partial function *literal*, because precedence rules require it have brackets when used inline.

Comment: Bah you've got a trick the Haskell answer should steal... :P

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES7), 107 bytes

```js
n=>[...Array(n)].reduce((a,_,x)=>[...a,...a.map(y=>[6*x*x,...y])],[[]]).filter(a=>eval(a.join`+`)**.5%1==0)
```

#### Demo

```js
let f =

n=>[...Array(n)].reduce((a,_,x)=>[...a,...a.map(y=>[6*x*x,...y])],[[]]).filter(a=>eval(a.join`+`)**.5%1==0)

console.log(f(6).map(a => JSON.stringify(a)).join('\n'))
console.log(f(10).map(a => JSON.stringify(a)).join('\n'))
```

#### Commented

```js
n =>                      // n = input
  [...Array(n)]           // generate a n-entry array
  .reduce((a, _, x) =>    // for each entry at index x:
    [                     //   update the main array a[] by:
      ...a,               //     concatenating the previous values with
      ...a.map(           //     new values built from the original ones
        y =>              //     where in each subarray y:
          [ 6 * x * x,    //       we insert a new element 6x² before
            ...y       ]  //       the original elements
      )                   //     end of map()
    ],                    //   end of array update
    [[]]                  //   start with an array containing an empty array
  )                       // end of reduce()
  .filter(a =>            // filter the results by keeping only elements for which:
    eval(a.join`+`) ** .5 //   the square root of the sum
    % 1 == 0              //   gives an integer
  )                       // end of filter()
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
Ḷ²6×ŒPSÆ²$Ðf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9qZWxsef//4bi2wrI2w5fFklBTw4bCsiTDkGb/w4fFkuG5mP//MTA)

Output is a list of subsets including `0`s and the empty subset.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 49 bytes

Brute force approach

```
Select[Subsets[6Range[#]^2],Sqrt@Tr@#~Mod~1==0&]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7Pzg1JzW5JDq4NKk4taQ42iwoMS89NVo5Ns4oVie4sKjEIaTIQbnONz@lztDW1kAtVu1/QFFmXkl0moOhQex/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), 15 bytes

```
ò_²*6Ãà k_x ¬u1
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=8l+yKjbD4CBrX3ggrHUx&input=OAotUg==)

---

### Explanation

Generate on array of integers from 0 to input (`ò`) and pass each through a function (`_   Ã`), squaring it (`²`) & mutiplying by 6 (`*6`). Get all the combinations of that array (`à`) and remove those that return truthy (`k`) when passed through a function (`_`) that adds their elements (`x`), gets the square root of the result (`¬`) and mods that by 1 (`u1`)